# use OpenCV cvProjectPoints2 function

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I just want to give this function a test. And yet, it came with some incomprehensive errors at the [beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624293/opencv-homogeneous-coordinates-are-not-supported-when-using-cvprojectpoints2), which I finally found the solution. That is: both `objectPoints` & `imagePoints` have to be changed to `CV_32FC3` & `CV_32FC2` respectively, the code works fine. 
For this, the documentation of OpenCV is so erroneous which tells that all matrix representation can work

Getting over this bug, I have incorrect output:

[image]

The projected image points are irrational (of course, I've checked my input data).

Has anyone experienced with this function of OpenCV, giving correct projection?

Edit 01:
output(2,2) = -1.#QNAN000

=> can this be a clue to know the cause of error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cause is from my lack of experience working with OpenCV matrices. After 2 dyas working, testing with CvMat and Mat. I've learnt a few poitns:

- create a good matrix display function so that it will not show awkward numbers which I have found good suggestion from this post [Multi channel Mat display function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179059/multi-channel-mat-display-function/12179129#12179129)
- be careful when you feed/init OpenCV matrices with your predefined data, careful with 1-channel or multi-channel matrices. Give it some trials before you know how OpenCV understands your input data
- acknowledge that cvProjectPoints2 does not get single channel matrices as in/outputs

after all debugging, my output is like this:

[image]

and this is pretty closed to my real object points & image points & calibrated camera matrix