# difference between CV_32FC3 and CV_64FC3 in OpenCV?

Tags: debugging, opencv, matrix

I was testing around with OpenCV matrices and the display function and had this bug. It took me more than half a day to reveal it:

I originally tried to display OpenCV matrices regardless of the type of matric e.g. CvMat or Mat, ...
with a display method recommended by Mr vasile from another post of mine [Multi channel Mat display function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179059/multi-channel-mat-display-function/12179129#12179129)

The display method simply fetches all data of the matrix to cout stream

this is my program:

```
// First: CV_32FC3 works OK

float objpts[12] = {0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0};
CvMat objptsmat = cvMat( 1, 4, CV_32FC3, objpts);  
CvMat* objectPoints = &objptsmat;
CvMatShow(objectPoints);
getchar();
```

output:

[image]

```
// Second: CV_64FC3 crashes

float objpts[12] = {0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0};
CvMat objptsmat = cvMat( 1, 4, CV_64FC3, objpts);  
CvMat* objectPoints = &objptsmat;
CvMatShow(objectPoints);
getchar();
```

output: 
[image]

they should be both the same. Right??!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second example, you should have the array declared as

```
double objpts[12] = {0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 105, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

You can read `CV_xxtCn` as

- xx: number of bits
- t: type (F = floating point type, S = signed integer, U = unsigned integer)
- n: number of channels

Comment: thank you!! so when array is float(double), CvMat should be CV_32F(CV_64F) and I've tested both cases. This is more like strictly compatible, float cannot go with CV_64F and vice versa

Comment: Computers are dumb, so you need to tell them exactly what type to expect. When you tell `CvMat` that it should read 12 times 64 bits, but you only supply 12 times 32 bits, then your program will read/write  memory, that it should not access.